# rename table name in beamer

Tags: beamer

hello i need rename `cuadro` for `tabla`. i use this command but no work.

```
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
```

the command work in latex normal but no beamer presentation. the beamer presentation show CUADRO y i want show TABLA. Someone had the same problem?

thanks and greetings.

Comment: If you are interested, Javier Bezos explains [here](http://tex-tipografia.com/spanish2.html), among other `spanish-babel` decisions, what's the difference between `tabla` and `cuadro`, both `table` in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `spanish` module for babel offers various ways to do this without using `\AtBeginDocument`.

One possibility is to redefine the corresponding `\spanish<element-name>` command implemented by the module:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\renewcommand\spanishtablename{Tabla}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
A
\caption{test table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It also provides the option `es-tabla`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
A
\caption{test table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It also has the `mexico` option that, amongst other things, translates "table" as "tabla" (as it is customary in Mexico and other Latin American countries):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
A
\caption{test table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Please always post complete documents not just fragments.

As always you need to add it to the language specific hook or if just using one language redefine after begin document, once the language is set up.

This produces Tabla for me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
aa
\caption{kkk}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```